# Wildcards in Hazelcast Subscriptions

Tags: hazelcast

How do I subscribe to topics based on wildcards? For instance, if there are two topics: account.transactions and account.returns, can I subscribe to account.*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that, however you can use `HazelcastInstance::getDistributedObjects` try for ITopic instance (`if (obj instanceOf ITopic`) and use `DistributedObject::getName` to test the name for your pattern.

Comment: Sounds not very efficent.

Comment: Because of the instanceof? That's a pretty efficient operation in newser Java versions (Java 6+). Sure not as fast as returning only those objects but internally those distributed objects are in one big list, therefore the instanceof check would happen internally, nothing won :) (PS: always free to hold your own lists, right?)